# Spring Boot properties usage in Apache Camel route

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

Is this possible to use Spring Boot properties in Apache Camel route? @Value is working fine but is this possible to directly place in place holders of expressions.

**Update:** I know PropertiesComponent but which will be one more configuration apart from Applicaiton.yml that I don't like to have.

**application.yml**

```
sftp:
  host:     10.10.128.128
  user:     ftpuser1
  password: ftpuser1password  
  path:     /tmp/inputfile/test1
```

**Spring Boot Apache Camel Route:**

```
 @Value("${sftp.user}")
    private String sftpUser;

    @Value("${sftp.host}")
    private String sftpHost;

    @Value("${sftp.password}")
    private String sftpPassword;

    @Value("${sftp.path}")
    private String sftpInPath;

    from("sftp://"+sftpUser+"@"+sftpHost+sftpInPath+"?delete=true&password="+sftpPassword)
//this is working

    from("sftp://${sftp.user}@${sftp.host}${sftp.path}?password=${sftp.password}")
// is this possible something like this?
```

Comment: Did you try do this?

Comment: Yes which is not working, it says as empty.Also it could not bind @ByeBye thanks for reply

Comment: Have you seen this: http://camel.apache.org/properties.html

Comment: @DariusX. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of injecting all you properties to separate fields you can inject your full link like that:

```
@Value("#{'sftp://'+'${sftp.user}'+'@'+'${sftp.host}'+'${sftp.path}'+'?delete=true&password='+'${sftp.password}'}")
private String fullLink;
```

Then, you can use it in `from` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.which was helpful.

Answer (score 10):

You can use property placeholders (http://camel.apache.org/properties.html) in Camel like this:

```
from("sftp://{{sftp.user}}@{{sftp.host}}{{sftp.path}}?password={{sftp.password}}")
```

Comment: Thanks I will check this

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it locally but you could try to use [this](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html), by adding this properties component into the camel context( maybe u need to override the camel context configuration). Then you could  use {{file.uri}} inside the from parts.

```
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("classpath:com/mycompany/myprop.properties");
context.addComponent("properties", pc);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, As we have single point of contact application.properties, this(PropertiesComponent) will be overhead of the Application.

Comment: Sorry but why don't you point to the application.properties which spring boot creates?

Comment: That is good idea till I dont know whether which will support .yml or only properties.Thanks I will check this.